# Android app to extend Play Store wishlist and allow creating quick notes about apps

Tags: android, annotation, play-store, wishlist

I need an Android (KitKat) app  to quickly add apps to an **organized** wishlist.  Google's integrated Play Store wishlist is far too simple to be useful.  Being able to assign categories or tags is essential.

Also, being able to add notes for each app is a *requirement*.  If I uninstall an app, I want to be able to write a quick note as to *why* I uninstalled it.

A useful feature would be to include cost information, so that I can bookmark expensive apps and easily check back to see if they are on sale or the price has been lowered.

**Speed** and **ease-of-use** are very important.  Accomplishing the task with *as few clicks as possible* is key.

The great app **Marketmarks** can do all these things, and I built up an organized database with over 1000 apps.  But it turns out the Restore component of the Backup / Restore process does not work properly.   When I switched devices, all my hard work became unusable.  (The author has been notified, but he may not read/write English.)   :(

The app you recommend can be something integrated into the Play Store, or a separate app store altogether.